# Runtime.exec() throwing Working Directory: null Environment: null

Tags: java, process, adb, android-uiautomator

Error running exec(). Command:

```
set `ps | grep <package name>`
```

Working Directory: null Environment: null

I am running the following command to get the process id for my app

```
private int getProcessId(String packageName) {
    int processid = -1;
    try {
        runADBCommand(new String[] {"set `ps | grep " + packageName + "`"});
        processid = Integer.parseInt(runADBCommand(new String[]{"print $2"}));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Process id: " + processid);
    return processid;
}
```

The runADBCommand function looks like this:

```
private String runADBCommand(String[] adbCommand) throws IOException {
    String returnValue = "", line;
    InputStream inStream = null;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(adbCommand);
        inStream = process.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader brCleanUp = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
        while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine()) != null) {
            returnValue = returnValue + line + "\n";
        }
        brCleanUp.close();
        try {
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I am trying to run this on non rooted Moto G device and also cut, awk are not
available in device shell for me to directly get the pid.

Comment: That's not an exception, so it wasn't thrown. Provide the entire stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You're running a `set` command, which is a shell command, but you're not running a shell. So it can't possibly work. You need to add `sh -c` in front of it. But I don't see the point. The result of the `set` will be lost when the shell exits. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: this code is in UIAutomator and thus it run directly within ADB shell and so I need not put sh -c

Answer (score -1):

Somehow I found that set command did not work on non rooted device and moto G does not have a awk or cut as default commands, so instead of directly getting the PID from adb shell, I tried a different approach.

```
private int getProcessId() {
    try {
        String process = runADBCommand("ps <<last 15 characters of packagename>>");
        return Integer.parseInt(process.split("\n")[1].trim().split(" ")[3]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This function gave the result out perfectly.

Also if you noticed I am now not sending an array as command but just a string, runADBCommand for this is same as in question, the only difference being it accepts a string instead of an array of strings.